# LDAP integration with jBilling

Tags: java, linux, ldap, openldap

How can i use LDAP authentication for jBilling?

Comment: bounty for user who can help to use ldap with Jbilling 3.0

Answer (score 1):

LDAP is on the jBilling roadmap:

http://www.jbilling.com/product/road-map

Comment: Yes, there is support of LDAP for version => 2.0.0.
But there is no any documentation for it. (Current version 2.2.0)

Comment: The link is broken and LDAP and JBilling don't seem to be mentioned much in search engine indices: anyone have any relevant fresh information?